# Script issue about " link redirecting "

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

Here's the script:

```
<script>
if(document.location.href.indexOf('https://thedomain.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling') > -1) { 
document.location.href = 'https://thedomain.com/pages/bestsellers';
}
</script>
```

Question is, how can i make the code so that when i put https://thedomain.com/////////////////////////////////////////collections/all?sort_by=best-selling

it would still send me to the designated link. Or whenever i duplicate any of the "/" "?" "_" "=" "-" characters. When i do duplicate those characters in my website it doesn't redirect to the page i want it to go ( or it doesn't do it automatically)

Bottom line is i don't want to be forced to do this (its inefficient):

```
<script>
if(document.location.href.indexOf('https://thedomain.com/////////////////////////////////////////collections/all?sort_by=best-selling') > -1) { 
document.location.href = 'https://thedomain.com/pages/bestsellers';
}
</script>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: you could also test only on the query string: `if(document.location.search === '?sort_by=best-selling')`

Comment: Also its better to make sure you don have duplicate urls with different amount of: "/" "?" "_" "=" "-" . Google will not like it and rank your page lower. its better to fix this root problem (having different urls for the same page) then try to solve it in code here.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following reg-ex to remove extra slashes from your URL :

```
var correctURL= document.location.href.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1"); 
//removes every slash that follows after a character that is not : and then a slash.
```

Now you can validate against this url:

```
if(correctURL.indexOf('https://thedomain.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling') > -1) { 
    document.location.href = 'https://thedomain.com/pages/bestsellers';
}
```

Comment: i added the line of code you suggested and it didn't work :( How would i go into adding this?